# Local springboot project connection to remote Redis timeout

Tags: spring-boot, redis, sentinel

I have set up redis sentinel mode on a remote server through docker, which includes one master node and two slave nodes.

The remote sentinel configuration is as follows:

```
port 26379
daemonize no
pidfile "/var/run/redis-sentinel.pid"
logfile "/usr/local/redis/logs/sentinel-26379.log"
dir "/data"
sentinel monitor mymaster 172.10.0.3 6379 2
sentinel auth-pass mymaster xxxxxxxx
```

The local engineering configuration is as follows:

```
  redis:
    sentinel:
      master: mymaster
      nodes: {remoteip}:26379,{remoteip}:26380,{remoteip}:26381
    password: xxxxxxxx
    lettuce:
      pool:
        enabled: true
        max-active: 20
        max-idle: 5
        max-wait: 1000ms
        min-idle: 1
```

But running the local springboot project reported an error：connection timed out: /172.10.0.3:6379

Obviously, the local attempt to connect is the intranet address of the main node of the remote server. I think it should be to connect to remoteip, but I don't know how to configure it

how to configure it